# TypeError: must be str, not float - linear Regression

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, linear-regression

I am getting a TypeError: must be str, not float error for my linear regression when I have copied the code from a previous chart and just updated the variables. Below are my dependencies as well as the code. the (slope, intercept) line is where the error is pointing to. Any help is appreciated. I am fairly new to coding and just cannot seem to figure this one out.

````
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import requests
import time
import json
import random
import scipy.stats as st

from sklearn import datasets
from scipy.stats import linregress
from pprint import pprint```


x_values = city_data.loc[city_data['Latitude']>=0]
y_values = city_data['Temperature']

(slope, intercept, rvalue, pvalue, stderr) = stats.linregress(x_values, y_values)
regress_values = x_values * slope + intercept
line_eq = "y = " + str(round(slope,2)) + "x + " + str(round(intercept,2))

plt.scatter(x_values, y_values, marker="o", facecolors="green", edgecolors="black",
            s=30, alpha=0.75)
plt.plot(x_values,regress_value,"r-")
plt.annotate(line_eq,(20,36),fontsize=15,color="red")
plt.xlim(-50, 85)
plt.ylim(10,95 )
plt.title('City Norther Hemisphere Latitude vs Temperature (10/10/2020)')
plt.xlabel('Latitude')
plt.ylabel('Tempurature (F)')
plt.show()```
````

Comment: Which line gave you the error?

Comment: (slope, intercept, rvalue, pvalue, stderr) = stats.linregress(x_values, y_values)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line to:

```
city_data = city_data[city_data['Latitude']>=0]
x_values = city_data['Latitude']
```

Comment: did a print of the x_values and it's printing my entire dataframe...

Comment: And this is what you intended?

Comment: It is not. I just need the values in the "Latitude" column that are greater than or equal to zero

Comment: I just figured it out, I set the the .loc to a variable and then pulled the series from that variable into the x_values, if that makes sense.